# element ui: unable to call resetField to reset single number inputs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I want to reset single number input fields in element ui...

According to the documentation there should be the method resetField:
https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/form#form-item-methods

My number inputs are part of a ruleForm following the example code:

I tried:

```
this.ruleForm.survivalYears.resetField()
```

and

```
this.$refs['ruleForm'].survivalYears.resetField()
```

What am I doing wrong? My current dirty hack looks like this:

```
this.ruleForm.survivalYears = -1 // assign some value to rerender
delete this.ruleForm.survivalYears
```

Comment: Sometime $refs is an array when inside a loop.  Have you tried `this.$refs['ruleForm'][0].survivalYears.resetField()`?

Comment: Also is element given `ref='ruleForm'`?

Comment: When i try as you suggested I get the following: `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'survivalYears' of undefined"`

Comment: I do not understand the element question, sorry

Comment: Post the template code that declares the element you are referencing

Comment: `<el-form :model="ruleForm" :rules="rules" ref="ruleForm" class="ruleForm" label-position="right"
                     label-width="180px">`

Comment: I basically copy pasted the example from the docs and added / removed a couple of fields according to my needs:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JqRVmE?%20via%20@CodePen

Comment: Based on the codepen, you would use: ` this.$refs['ruleForm'].resetFields();`  I am not sure why you have `survivalYears` in there.  That seems to just be a data member of your component.

Comment: `resetFields()` works to reset the whole form as you described. However I only want to reset singular form items with the `resetField()` method. Note the missing `s`

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, why not use `clearable` attribute on `el-input`?

> Note: You cannot use `clearable` attribute with combination of
>   `readonly` attribute

```
<el-input clearable></el-input>
```

This itself will solve your issue, even otherwise if you still like to use `resetField`, then, to my knowledge there are 2 ways you can do this:

a: If you like to take reference of `<el-form ref="myForm">`.

```
resetForm() {
  var index = Object.keys(this.formObj).indexOf('myName');
  this.$refs.myForm.fields[index].resetField();
}
```

b: If you like to take reference of `<el-form-item ref="myName">`

```
resetForm() {
  this.$refs.myName.resetField()
}
```